# Why am I seeing my messages in my inbox from my previous account?

Tags: support, help-center, global-inbox

I've asked (through the contact form) several times in the last 48 hours whether my previous and new account can be un-merged. It seems it has been automatically merged together without my approval.

The whole point of deleting my older previous account and signing up for a new account was so that I had a clean slate, and thus no messages from previous accounts.

Notice that my account was not suspended since it can not be deleted if it is (as far as I know).

So far I haven't got any "human" reply from any moderator / employee.
Maybe someone here has an idea of how to un-merge the two.

Thanks

Comment: You'll probably have to wait for a bit more than 48 hours, SE has a bit of a backlog of messages they need to process at the moment from what I heard.

Comment: Okay thank you for letting me know. 
No problem waiting :)

Comment: When they unmerge accounts, they don't go through every intricate detail of your accounts to restore them to the *exact* way they were before. Inbox messages make absolutely no difference whatsoever to your account. They're just messages that only you can even see, and they're not going to go through them all to determine which messages should be connected to which account. Just ignore them.

Comment: Also, I don't see any events in your user history that accounts were ever merged together. Did you actually create a new account or did you just login to an old account you thought you had deleted?

Comment: No merging should take place at all without the users approval. Unless that user is trying to bypass something (which I am not). 

If there hadn't any merging taken place without a users consent, they wouldn't have to "go through every intricate detail of your accounts to restore them to the exact way they were before".

It's probably something that is happening automatically, and the fact that it's happening and is takes them almost 48 hours to reply to after writing about it, is disappointing.

Comment: @Brain: 48 hours ago was Saturday morning US time. Don't expect to-the-second support on weekends (on weekdays either).

Comment: I created a new account, based on a new email address. After which I never logged in or used / merged anything of the older account. 

Also after my account got deleted, I received a deletion notification of it. 

When I click on the older posts, I can see that they have been made anonymous (as they should be after someones account is deleted). 
But I shouldn't be able to see them in my inbox, as the previous (deleted account) has nothing to do with the newly created account.

Comment: Brian, it's a 3 day weekend. They're behind. Even if it were only 48 hour waiting time, those are certainly WORK days.

Comment: I'll be happy to wait to receive support. 
An idea in this case (if they are running behind with answering tickets) could be creating a automatic notification that get's send by email that they're running behind or that it's a 3 day weekend and because of that there is a delay answering tickets. 

At least it will clarify that someone has to wait and that person knows why.

Comment: @Brain You must have used the same login credentials as last time if it got connected back to your [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/237116/brain) account. It looks like your previous Stack Overflow account *was* deleted as you requested. Your Stack Exchange network profile was *not*. When you created a new Stack Overflow account, your credentials matched your network account and you were linked back to that account. Your old messages were stored on the network account, and since you're now linked back to that network account, you can see all of your previous messages.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this for me. 
How can I solve this issue?
Or can you do this for me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's been waiting for more than 3 days for a reply regarding my question. The delay could have been blamed on a 3 day weekend like Alex K pointed out, or because SE has a backlog of messages to handle like @Mad scientist mentioned. 

But now it looks more like the people behind SE are simply unprofessional to handle messages such as mine. Especially since I send the message more than once through the appropriate channel and have raised this matter as a question on stackoverflow meta. 

Very disappointing!